# FFMPEG -ss copy .m3u8 video's is slow

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have multiple video's consisting of a m3u8 file in combination with a bunch of .ts files (10 seconds a piece). I would like to be able to copy pieces from these video's in order to present only the wanted piece of a longer video to the user. The video's range from 30 minutes to 3 hours, and the piece to copy from the video can be up to 1 hour long.

The FFMPEG command I use for this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i /media-storage/3/308/video.m3u8 -to 00:10:25 -hls_time 10 -start_number 1 -hls_playlist_type vod -c copy /media-storage/test/video.m3u8
```

There does not need to be any re-encoding or converting, but the operation above takes about 30 seconds. (which is only 10 minutes)
Is there any way to improve this command to make it a bit quicker? The cutting does not need to be frame precise.

I use the latest FFMPEG release and my OS is CentOS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue with the poor performance in the above command.
Turns out the SMB NAS where my data is stored is not very fast when copying data. When I use the above command on the local machine the response is almost instant.